# where is this shloka from: uccenninda ānaṅda maraviṃda vilocanaḥ?

Tags: scripture, krishna, mantras, reference-request, shloka

Trying to identify the source of this shloka

> uccenninda ānaṅda maraviṃda vilocanaḥ

उच्चेंनिंद आनंद मरविंद विलोचनः

```
उच्चेन्निन्द (uccenninda): High praise
आनंद (ānaṅda): Joy, bliss
मरविंद (maraviṃda): Lord of death (Yama)
विलोचनः (vilocanaḥ): Eyed, having eyes
```

any suggestions are appreciated.